# Python and redis. Make queries more efficient

Tags: python, redis

My Python code (part of a Django site) queries data from a redis database and loads it into a Pandas dataframe. I'm new to redis, and I think I'm not using the redis library as efficiently as I could.

The database keys are timestamps in epocho format. The values are all json strings. Here's a sample:

```
Keys:
['1622235486.006474000', '1622235486.006760000', '1622235486.114156000']
Values:
['{"timestampx": "1622235486.006474000", "length": "1416", "dscp": "0", "srcip": "172.17.4.2", "destip": "172.16.1.2"}', '{"timestampx": "1622235486.006760000", "length": "108", "dscp": "0", "srcip": "172.16.1.2", "destip": "172.17.4.2"}', '{"timestampx": "1622235486.114156000", "length": "112", "dscp": "0", "srcip": "172.17.4.2", "destip": "172.16.1.2"}']
```

Four questions about my code:

1. First I get all keys with .keys(). Then I filter the list of keys. Then I use .mget(keys). Making two connections to redis (once to get keys, again to get values) seems inefficient. Is there a better method?
2. Some of the keys aren't epoch timestamps. They start with "1_", and they contain None values. I have to filter those out. I use a separate line of code to do that. Can I do that as part of the keys() function?
3. I also have a line to sort the keys. Can I ask redis to return them sorted?
4. Finally, is there an argument for .mget() that filters out None values?

```
import redis
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd
import json

INTERVAL = 5

r = redis.StrictRedis(**redis_config)
filter = datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=INTERVAL) 

recentkeys = [] 
allkeys = r.keys(pattern="*")  #Question 1. Is the best query keys() passed to mget()?
allkeys = [x for x in allkeys if not x.startswith('1_')] #Question 2. Can I pass a filter to redis and have it filter the response?

    for k in allkeys:
        if float(k) > float(filter.timestamp()):
            recentkeys.append(k)
    recentkeys.sort()          #Question 3. Can redis return a sorted set? 
   
    values = r.mget(recentkeys)    
    values = [x for x in values if x != None]    #Question 4. Can redis filter out None values?

    recent_values = pd.DataFrame(map(json.loads, values))
```